# In a network, are more links between nodes the better?

Tags: graph, graph-theory

Theoretically, is complete graph desired (the best)? Because there are links to each nodes? Any references would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That really depends what you mean by "the best".  If you're talking about maximizing flow, you will likely approach the theoretical upper bound on flow by having a complete graph with appropriate weights.  However, if you're really talking about "best" in some real system, a complete graph is unlikely to be the network that one would construct for most things simply owing to the wasteful expense of doing so.

It seems like your question is related to the [Max-flow min-cut theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max-flow_min-cut_theorem).  Note that the minimal cut in a complete graph is always going to be of size at least `|V|-1`, as every vertex has at least that many edges.